# Is there an blockIdx equivalent for thread_groups or thread_block_tiles?

Tags: cuda

I started using cooperative_groups and find myself often to wish for a method that replaces the second line.

```
thread_block_tile<32> tile = tiled_partition<32>(this_thread_block());
int tileId = this_thread_block().thread_rank()/tile.size();
```

My assumption here is that:

1. `tileId` is the same for every thread in the same tile.
2. The `tileId` goes from `0` to `(this_thread_block().size())/tile.size()`.

I looked into https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cooperative-groups/ and https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/9.2/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#thread-block-tiles-cg. In both sources there is an example similar to:

```
thread_group tile4 = tiled_partition(this_thread_block(), 4);
if (tile4.thread_rank()==0) 
printf("Hello from tile4 rank 0: %d\n",
       this_thread_block().thread_rank());
```

that produces:

```
Hello from tile4 rank 0: 0
Hello from tile4 rank 0: 4
Hello from tile4 rank 0: 8
Hello from tile4 rank 0: 12
```

Which seems to fit with the assumptions.

I am left with two questions:

1. Does my assumptions hold for the presented way to calculate `tileId`?
2. Is there an simpler way to achieve the desired behavior that I missed?

Example usecase

```
__device__
int someFkt(thread_block_tile<16> tile, int* data)
{
   // some stuff that works best using 16 threads
}

__global__
void some_kernel(int* data)
{
   thread_block_tile<16> tile = tiled_partition<16>(this_thread_block());
   int tileId = this_thread_block().thread_rank()/tile.size();
   int result = someFkt(tile,data+tileId*tile.size());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is correct that the

> `tileId` goes from `0` to `(this_thread_block().size())/32`

if the tile size was `32`.

And the `tileId` is indeed the same for all the threads in the same tile. These `tileId`s are also the same for all the blocks, so all the blocks have `tileId` 0, 1, ...

Only `thread_block` [provide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#groups-blocks-cg) its index:

> whereas `thread_block` provides the following additional block-specific
>   functionality:
>
> `dim3 group_index(); // 3-dimensional block index within the grid`
>
> `dim3 thread_index(); // 3-dimensional thread index within the block`

---

Not sure if this was a typo in your example use case:

> ```
> int tileId = this_thread_block().thread_rank()/32;
> ```

The correct from is:

```
int tileId = this_thread_block().thread_rank()/16;
```

Comment: There was a typo (16 instead of 32), thanks for the catch. Is the `.size()` in your correction is a typo?

Comment: @generic_opto_guy it was a typo, thanks. I fixed it.